# Zsh not hitting ~/.profile

Tags: ubuntu, zsh

I've just installed zsh on my Ubuntu system. It seems zsh isn't executing ~/.profile on init. To my best understanding, this should be an automatic behavior. What am I missing?

Answer (score 391, accepted):

#### `.profile` vs. `.zprofile`

Zsh runs `~/.zprofile`, not `~/.profile`, when it is invoked as a login shell. The reason is that zsh has enough incompatibilities with standard shells to break scripts.

Zsh does run `~/.profile` if it is called as `sh` or `ksh`. But if your objective is to get a zsh prompt when you log in, that's no help.

You can make `/bin/sh` your login shell and include `export SHELL=/bin/zsh` in your `~/.profile`. Then when you open a terminal, the terminal will launch zsh (except for a few terminal emulators don't obey the `$SHELL` setting). But you will still have `sh` when you log in over ssh. This can be remedied by including `exec zsh` at the end of `~/.profile` (this replaces the running shell by zsh), but you need to be careful only to do that for interactive logins and not when `~/.profile` is included from other scripts such as the X session start (a good test is the name of the parent process obtained by `ps -o comm= $PPID`: if it's `sshd` or `su`, then it's safe to `exec`).

The easiest solution to both work with zsh and run `~/.profile` is to create a `~/.zprofile` that enters sh emulation mode while it runs `~/.profile`:

```
emulate sh
. ~/.profile
emulate zsh
```

If you have a recent enough zsh (on Ubuntu, that means since lucid, I think), you can simplify this to `emulate sh -c '. ~/.profile'`.

#### `.zprofile` vs. `.zshrc`

The file `~/.profile` is loaded by *login* shells. The login shell is the first process that is started when you log in in text mode, for example on a text console or via ssh. By default, on most Linux machines, the login shell is bash, but you can change it with the `chsh` command, or through some other tool such as the “User Settings” in Ubuntu. When it's a login shell, bash reads `~/.bash_profile` if it exists and `~/.profile`, whereas zsh reads only `~/.zprofile` (because its syntax is not completely compatible with a traditional sh). Under most configurations, `~/.profile` is also loaded by the X session startup scripts when you log in in a graphical display manager.

When you start a terminal emulator and get a shell prompt, or when you start a shell explicitly, you get a shell that is not a login shell. Since `~/.profile` (or `~/.zprofile`) is for commands that you want to execute when you log in, a non-login shell doesn't read this file. Instead, when you start an interactive zsh, it reads `~/.zshrc`. (Zsh reads `~/.zshrc` in all interactive shells, whether they are login shells are not; bash, strangely, never reads `~/.bashrc` in login shells.)

Typically, `~/.profile` contains environment variable definitions, and might start some programs that you want to run once when you log in or for the whole session; `~/.zshrc` contains things that must be done for every shell instance, such as alias and function definitions, shell option settings, completion settings, prompt settings, key bindings, etc.

Comment: Great answer! I've created ~/.zprofile and put the line as you suggested, but it doesn't seem to do anything. Perhaps I should put it in .zshrc?

Comment: @shmichael: Given your reaction, I may not have interpreted your question the way you intended it. Does the second section I've added to my answer help?

Comment: yes, hit the spot. So if I understand correctly I would want e.g. PATH declarations on .zprofile and aliases on .zshrc.

Comment: @user1419674 Thank you for the correction, but do not add a change log to posts. The site has a built-in revision history.

Comment: When I ssh into remote machine `ssh -Y -4 -t -Y user@IP \"zsh\""` seems like `.zprofile` is not loaded, is it a normal behavior?

Comment: @alper Yes. You aren't running a login shell, and whatever that non-login shell is, you're telling it to run the command `zsh`. If you want to read `.zprofile`, tell zsh that it's a login shell: `ssh -Y4t user@IP zsh --login`

Answer (score 187):

### Short answer for impatient people:

1. `~/.profile` is not loaded by `zsh` at login.
2. `zsh` loads `~/.zprofile` at login.
3. `zsh` loads `~/.zshrc` when starting a new terminal session.

Need more info? Look at Gilles' superb answer!

Comment: love this TLDR.

Comment: This comment makes my ADHD **very** happy (^.^)'

Comment: ok, for the comments, what *does* load `.profile` if not zsh?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Traditional `sh` reads the file `~/.profile` at startup when it's a login shell. For info on `sh` vs. `bash` look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash

Answer (score 31):

In addition to Gilles's answer, with a reasonably recent version of zsh you can do this:

```
[[ -e ~/.profile ]] && emulate sh -c 'source ~/.profile'
```

...Which will source the .profile file with zsh's sh-mode in effect. And it's only active during the source. So you do not have to save the current option state in order to replay it again after sourcing.

Comment: I have this in my ~/.zprofile, but for some reason the statements in ~/.profile are not available in my shell. Ubuntu 15.04; zsh 5.0.7

Comment: Hard to diagnose without code.

Comment: I just tried again, and it looks like it is working now. Not sure if it was fixed at some point or what happened. zsh version is 5.1.1 now.

Answer (score 11):

I have `.zprofile` compatible with `.profile` (contains only PATH changes), hence only needing:

```
ln -s .profile .zprofile
```

Comment: simple 1, line solution. ✨

Answer (score 2):

The *zsh* documentation I have on hand only mentions `/etc/profile` and `~/.profile` for login shells in *sh*/﻿*ksh* compatibility mode.

```
% zsh --version
zsh 4.3.10 …
% cat ~/.profile
echo 'Running ~/.profile...'
```

Native mode login shell (argv[0] starts with `-`) does not use `~/.profile` (it will use `~/.zprofile` though):

```
% zsh -c 'exec -a -zsh zsh' </dev/null
```

(no output)

*sh*/﻿*ksh* compatability mode login shells uses .profile:

```
% zsh -c 'exec -a -sh zsh' </dev/null
Running ~/.profile...
% zsh -c 'exec -a -ksh zsh' </dev/null
Running ~/.profile...
```