# .bash_profile not sourced

Tags: macos, mac, .bash-profile

I have a `.bash_profile` file that I added some stuff to (aliases and color and some git stuff) and when I open iTerm and source it then everything's fine and I have everything but when I close iTerm and reopen it then no colors and no aliases until I source it again.

What should I do to permanently source it?

Is it maybe sourcing another file? How can I check that?

EDIT: I checked my iTerm preferences, and the "login shell" option is checked
so I imagine it should source it when i open iTerm.

Comment: `.bash_profile` should be sourced automatically. Does it work with Terminal.app? In your iTerm settings, what is the *Command* being called under *Preferences » Profiles » Default » General*?

Comment: no command, 'login shell' is checked

Comment: Does it work in Terminal? Have you tried temporarily moving `~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist` somewhere else?

Comment: This page and the answers helped me with this issue, but also errors in your .bash_profile can cause code not to execute, in my case it was a [ character in an unescaped password string that stopped subsequent commands executing

Comment: For me, I had to write `source ~/.bash_profile` in my `~/env.sh`. [This post](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/3807#issuecomment-187930190) basically helped me.

Comment: same problem i solved with `bash -l` or --login.

Comment: If you are using `zsh` instead of `bash`, the terminal will source `~/.zshrc` instead of `~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok so I dug deeper into it and it's trying to source `.profile` and I, instead,  had `.bash_profile`. So I created a `~/.profile` file and copied the content of `.bash_profile` into it, and then - WORKS! It is sourced whenever I start iTerm or Terminal.

Comment: If both `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.profile` exist and are readable, bash should only execute `~/.bash_profile` (see /usr/share/doc/bash/bash.html). Does `ls -l ~/.bash_profile` print something like `-rw-r--r-- 1 username`?

Comment: `ls -l ~/.bash_profile` prints `-rw-r--r--@ 1 username staff ... date` .  Is the @ a problem?

Comment: I am having this same problem. And when I run that command I get the same thing as you Etienne Low Decarie.

Answer (score 30):

It's also possible that your terminal shell is defaulting to sh instead of bash. You can verify this first:

```
 $ echo $SHELL
 /bin/tcsh
```

To change this to bash, you can go into your Terminal -> Preferences -> Startup tab, and change "Shell Opens With:" from "Default login shell" to Command and value "/bin/bash".

Alternately, you can change your default shell by executing the following command at the command prompt:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

After you do either of these, open a new shell window, and your .bash_profile should be sourced.

Comment: `chsh -s /bin/bash` worked for me.

Comment: Definitely need the leading "/"

Answer (score 4):

`.profile`, `.bash_profile` and similar files are **only sourced by "login" shells.** In other words, only when you log in to the system. Therefore it does not make sense to set aliases there.

Keep only environment variables (`export` commands) in `.bash_profile`. Use `~/.bashrc` for everything else. Source it from `.bash_profile` too.

Comment: OS X terminals launch login shells by default.

Comment: In my case, I am using mac zsh terminal, so I had to move the contents of my old .bash_profile to .zprofile, checkout this solution: https://superuser.com/a/187673/428141 that worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking on .bash_profile then I forgot to login and doesn't work, if you login your `.bash_profile` will work perfectly.

Try:

```
$ login
$ login: (your name here)
$ password: (your password here)
```

Answer (score 1):

`.bash_profile` is only sourced by `bash` on login shells. Any desktop environment is not a login shell. In `bash` it is NOT intended that `.bash_profile` or `.profile` get sourced when you open a Terminal window (in Linux, where a Terminal does not spawn a login shell).

So how and when are those files sourced? How would you solve this, for instance, in Xorg where `.profile` is also not sourced? I know this is not Linux, but I wanted to understand how other desktop environments deal with this.

On Xorg your `.xsessionrc` should actually source your `.profile`, because this file is sourced only once when your desktop launches. So this is the preferred solution, because you don't source your `.profile` unnecessary times.

With this it is also clear that `.profile` is intended as a place, where you define your persistent variables and they will probably never change and still propagate down to your terminal instances. Changing `.profile` would require you to relog your session.

So for Aqua (the desktop environment of macOS) it is only logical to do the same, but there is no equivalent to `.xsessionrc`. That's probably the reason why MacOS sources `.zprofile` when launching a terminal with `zsh`. It hasn't been sourced on the actual login of Aqua, so new Terminal windows spawn a login shell instead.

So, all you really have to do is change the default shell. My guess is that you just setup your Terminal to open `bash` via initial command. But this will not spawn a login shell and thus only `.bashrc` is sourced.

Just do `chsh -s /bin/bash` and reopen your Terminal. Now it will attempt to load the `.bash_profile` and if its missing, it will source the `.profile`. Please note that it, however, will not source `.bashrc` on login shells, so you want to put this at the end of your `.bash_profile`:

```sh
test ! -s "$HOME/.bashrc" || \. "$HOME/.bashrc"
```

Now having a `.bash_profile` will cause `bash` not to source `.profile`, so put also this in the top of your `.bash_profile`:

```sh
test ! -s "$HOME/.profile" || \. "$HOME/.profile"
```

I consider this to be the optimal solution, because is behaves like Apple decided it to behave for `zsh`. Login shells do spawn with Terminals and the desktop environment has nothing to source for the entire session. Other unix based distributions don't spawn login shells in their Terminals, but they offer a way to source something when the desktop environment launches.

It's not coherent, but it's important to understand the nuances. When you know where to put what and how to deal with it, you can essentially make a portable configuration. At least that's my motivation to switch back to `bash`. `zsh` is not the default shell for Linux distributions.

Comment: This also answers why when in a remote computer and activating bash, or any other shell, the *rc or *_profile will not be sourced. This is a very interesting answer to better understand and solve the problem in the most convenient way depending on any situation

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  I fixed it by going to iTerm > Preferences > General. Select your desired profile (if you have more than one) and toggle the Command option and input `/usr/local/bin/bash -l`. If you don't have Homebrew installed then it will likely be `/bin/bash -l`.  If you aren't sure, type the command $`which bash` and it will tell which executable you are running.  Moreover, if you are on OS X, I highly recommend learning why you want Homebrew and how to install it.  Note that its L and not I depending on your font.  By adding the flag `-l` it starts bash in login mode and NOT interactive mode.  If it starts in login mode then it will source your .bash_profile.  This worked for me, hopefully it will help you!