# .xsessionrc doesn't call, but it should

Tags: debian, xorg, gnome, session

I recently moved from Ubuntu to Debian 10 Buster (gnome).
I created  `~/.xsessionrc` file with this content:

```
if [ -r ~/.profile ]; then . ~/.profile; fi
```

When I restart (or login) still .profile didn't source. Do you know why?
I followed this manual:
https://wiki.debian.org/Xsession

Comment: After re-installing debian, It works fine. Should "turn it off and on again" ;)

Comment: I found out the main reason. It's because installing zsh. Read here to fix it if you have same problem: https://superuser.com/questions/187639/zsh-not-hitting-profile